# Defending Against Man-in-the-Middle Attacks

Tags: security, tcp, client-server

I'm writing a program for working with a client and a server, and it's interesting how to provide data protection. What are the man-in-the-middle attack protection strategies?

Comment: Signing using public key cryptography.

Comment: The close reason here is slightly misleading. There are not really multiple questions here. We used to have a "too broad" reason which included "lacks effort or demonstration of any research" but the correct close reason now would really be "needs details or clarity". Anyway, please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask;](/help/how-to-ask) perhaps you can still edit this into a form which is acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to add to the last answer. If you're using HTTP as connection protocol:

1. use HTTPS with TLS1.2
2. use key pinning to check if the server's certificate is valid
3. use HSTS to prevent additional future MitM Attacks (prevents HTTPS->HTTP downgrade attacks)
4. do not offer HTTP (or automatically upgrade to HTTPS)
5. if possible, use client-side ssl certificate validation to validate the client's identity
6. allow for perfect forward secrecy (PFS)

If you're using a custom protocol (not HTTPS) then:

1. implement TLSv1.2
2. use certificate pinning (at least server-side, if possible client-side)
3. make sure you implement perfect forward secrecy

Answer (score 1):

1. Enforce HTTPS and validate the CA.
2. Use the [Strict-Transport-Security Header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) to prevent SSL-stripping MITM attacks.
3. Encrypt the data using [Public Key Cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)
4. You can give a threshold to the response time(MITM attack will delay the response time), but this would work in an environment where you can almost certain that the valid responses will be under the threshold.